# 10 wickets in an innings in international matches

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics, icc, wicket

[Jim Laker](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/62814.html) and [Anil Kumble](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/63829.html) are the only 2 players who have taken 10 wickets in an innings in Test matches. Is there any other bowler who has taken 10 wickets in an innings in any kind of international format, including one-day internationals, Twenty20 internationals or any other international cricket organised by the ICC?

Comment: Just for clarification: taking a *10-wicket haul* often means taking 10+ wickets over the two innings of a Test match, which has been done many times. It's better to refer to taking *10 wickets in an innings*, so there's no misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm clueless about cricket, but why does this post have a score of -7?

Comment: @Lohoris Even I don't know what is wrong about this question.

Comment: Public service announcement: this question is being discussed on [meta](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/564/why-does-this-post-have-such-a-low-score).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any bowler who take 10 wicket haul in any kind of international format either Test, ODI or T20?

At present, only two players you have mentioned have taken [10 wickets in an innings in any type of international matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=11;filter=advanced;orderby=wickets;template=results;type=bowling;view=innings).

Best bowling figure in ODI is: 8.0-3-19-8 by Chaminda Vaas of Sri Lanka vs Zimbabwe as Colombo (SSC)    on 8 Dec 2001.

Have a look at:

- [Best figures in an innings in Test matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283203.html)
- [Best figures in an innings in ODI matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283204.html)
- [Best figures in an innings in T20I matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/283973.html)
- [Best figures in an innings in Under-19s Youth Test matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/336917.html)
- [Best figures in an innings in Under-19s Youth ODI matches](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/records/336918.html)

Comment: In Test, ODI and T20 I know but I don't about other international tournament like Under-19, Under-21, List-A, etc.

Comment: @mkr9 - Under-21 (AFAIK), List-A are not international tournament. I have edited for Under-19 Test and ODI.

Comment: why not there is world cup for all under-21,under-19 etc organised by ICC. Also for List -A matches, currently there is on going tournament hosted in South Africa.

Comment: @mkr9 - Tournament organised by ICC doesn't always mean it's international. The meaning of List-A is all One dayers matches including ODI.

Comment: I am not saying all Tournaments organised by ICC is a international tournament but in which different countries take part then will be it called.

Comment: @mkr9 - No. As you are talking about [SA tri-series](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/current/series/630758.html) it is not [an international tournament](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xKsSN.png).

Answer (score 5):

Mehboob Alam from Nepal took [all 10 wickets in a World Cricket League match against Mozambique in 2008](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/current/match/352381.html). Some very brief commentary on this feat can be found at the [Guinness World Records website](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/records-9000/first-bowler-to-take-10-wickets-in-a-limited-overs-international/), and a match report is available on [Cricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wcl/content/story/352471.html).

Comment: True but it was not an international match.

Comment: Nepal vs Mozambique is fairly clearly an international match. The OP's request includes "any kind of international format [...] organised by the ICC", so this is in scope.